# Given x points on a line, find a specific point x index i that has shortest sum of distance from all n points

Tags: dynamic-programming

given a line with points ( x1,x2,...xn) on the line. We have to find the point with the minimal distance between all other points. We are given that the points on these lines are not sorted. The algorithm that solves this problem should end in linear time.
I have been given this problem and have tried thinking of the solution with simplifying it and then using recursion. im getting stuck on how the distance between these points wont be like a constant.

Comment: Is the points all on Y axis and only x ordinates are given? what is the range of n? What is the range of x(i) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using recursive method you might want to consider memoization. For example you can pass a map to your method and everytime you calculate a new distance add it to the map.

Answer (score 0):

First lets try to find whats the answer given that we don’t need to think about time limits.

The answer here is you have to find the point that is in the middle if you sort all the points in some order through that line. The proof of this is:

Suppose there are 5 points like this: 
    x1……x2……x3……x4……x5

Lets assume sum of distance when the answer is x(i) is SD(i)

Let assume the answer is x1:
    SD(1) = (x2-x1) + (x3-x1) + (x4-x1) + (x5-x1)

But x2 is better than x1, because when you shift your answer point from x1 to x2 the sum of distance will decrease for 4 points and increase for only 1 point.

```
SD(2) = (x2-x1) + (x3-x2) + (x4-x2) + (x5-x2)
      = SD(1) - 4(x2-x1) + (x2-x1)  [decrease coz u shifted closer to 4 points and getting farther from 1 point]
      = SD(1) - 3(x2-x1)
```

So SD(2) < SD(1)

in the same way you can prove:

```
SD(1)>SD(2)>SD(3)<SD(4)<SD(5)
```

So for any value of N always middle point is the answer here. In case of even number of points take any mid point

Now that we have proved that the middle point is the answer that we are looking for. Lets now apply a sorting algorithm on the points and take the middle one.

Since you need to get a Linear time algorithm. You have to sort these points using some O(N) sort algorithm. In case values of x has a small range you can try count sort.

Comment: when you say sort in some order, the sorting is done in relation to what, like for instance is it being sorted from closest to origin point or in relation to each other.  thanks in advance

Comment: @AncientDragon, yes sorting based on closest to origin.